# How to correctly find CSC of an angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, calculator

Alright, so one of my questions is CSC (angle) -5. When I plug CSC in my calculator, it says "math error." I'm using a Casio fx-300 MS, and using shift + cos, then putting an angle, such as 90.

Comment: Shift + cos may mean Arccosine, which is different from cosecant (csc)

Comment: The cosecant is the reciprocal of the sine.

Comment: $ \ \sin^{-1} \ $ is not the reciprocal of sine and $ \ \cos^{-1} \ $ is not the reciprocal of cosine.  When -1 is written as an "exponent" next to the name of a trigonometric function, it denotes the _inverse_ trigonometric function.  You are getting an error because there is no angle with a cosine value of $ \ -5 \ $ .  If you want the cosecant of $ \ 5º \ $ , first make sure you are in "degree mode" , then take the **sine** of $ \ 5º \ $ , then ask for the reciprocal of that.

Answer (score 1):

While I am unfamiliar with your Casio FX-300 MS, remember that CSC(Θ) has reciprocal identities where:

Csc(θ)= 1/(Sin(θ))

So, if your question is Csc(θ)-5=Ans, try it as (1/Sin(θ) )-5=Ans and you should get the same answer you intended to get. I hope this helps.

*edit*: [Also, (again I do not know your calculator) Should it be shift + Sin by chance to work a Csc(θ)?]